# Implementing bootstrap-sass in jekyll

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll

i've installed correctly my gemfile and i configure correctly my _configure.yml how can i improve my bootstrap-sass.
i cannot display or implement bootstrap-sass in jekyll what's wrong?

> _assets
>
> - stylesheets
>   - bootstrap
>     - ...more bootstrap
>   - _bootstrap-compass.scss
>   - _bootstrap-sprockets.scss
>   - _bootstrap.scss
>   - _bootstrap-mincer.scss
>   - _fonts.scss
>   - _bootstrap.scss
>   - _responsive.scss
>   - main.css
> - javascripts
>   - boostrap
>     - more javascript
>   - main.js
>   - particle.js
>   - particle.min.js

```js
_assets/javascripts/main.js

//= require jquery 
//= require particles 
//= require particles.min 
//= require bootstrap 
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

```css
_assets/stylesheets/main.css

    body { margin: 60px auto; width: 70%; }
    
    a { text-decoration: none; color: #999; }
    a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
    @import "font-awesome-sprockets";
    @import "font-awesome";
    p, ul { font-size: 1.5em; line-height: 1.4em; color: #333; }
    
    @import "responsive"
    @import "fonts"
    @import "bootstrap"
    @import "bootstrap-sprockets"
    @import "bootstrap-mincer"
    @import "bootstrap-compass"
```

```html
  

  <div> _assets
      </li>
      <ul>
      <li> stylesheets</li>
        <ul>
          <li> bootstrap</li>
         <ul>
           <li>...more bootstrap</li></ul>
           <li> _bootstrap-compass.scss</li>
           <li> _bootstrap-sprockets.scss</li>
           <li> _bootstrap.scss</li>
           <li> _bootstrap-mincer.scss</li>
           <li> _fonts.scss</li>
           <li>  _bootstrap.scss</li>
           <li> _responsive.scss</li>
           <li>  main.css</li></ul>
           <li> javascripts</li>
           <ul> 
            <li>boostrap</li>
            <ul> 
             <li> more javascript</li>
           </ul>
           <li> main.js</li>
           <li>  particle.js</li>
           <li> particle.min.js</li>
         </ul>
       </ul>
     </div>
_includes/head.html

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/stylesheets/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}"></html>
```

i cannot recognize my css in my jekyll .. what i'm doing wrong with jekylls?
i've installed the gems i configured my _configure.yml

```js
_assets/javascripts/main.js

 //= require jquery 
 //= require particles 
 //= require particles.min 
 //= require bootstrap 
 //= require bootstrap.min
 //= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

```css
_assets/stylesheets/main.css

    body { margin: 60px auto; width: 70%; }
    
    a { text-decoration: none; color: #999; }
    a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
    @import "font-awesome-sprockets";
    @import "font-awesome";
    p, ul { font-size: 1.5em; line-height: 1.4em; color: #333; }
    
    @import "responsive"
    @import "fonts"
    @import "bootstrap"
    @import "bootstrap-sprockets"
    @import "bootstrap-mincer"
    @import "bootstrap-compass"
```

```html
_includes/head.html

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/stylesheets/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}"></html>
```